# java PreparedStatement.setFloat throws NullpointerException, Pstmt.setString ist allowed?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

Actually my whole Question ist in the Title. I have a Class that manages the inserts and deletings of my Invoice-Objects to my Sqlite DB.

```
public class Invoice {
    private String str1;
    private Float flt1;
    private String str2Null;
    private Float flt2Null;

    public Invoice(String str1, Float flt1){
        this.str1 = str1;
        this.flt1 = flt1;
   }

  getters & setters...
}


public class InvoiceManager{
    ...Konstruktor...

    public int insertInvoice(Invoice invoice) throws Exception{
        try {
             PreparedStatement stmt = databaseConnection.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO invoice (str1, flt1, str2Null, flt2Null) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
             stmt.setString(1, invoice.getStr1());
             stmt.setFloat(2, invoice.getFlt1());
             stmt.setString(3, invoice.getStr2Null());
             stmt.setFloat(4, invoice.getFlt2Null());
     ....
```

So when I want to insert sth to the DB and Str2Null = null, it works and it write NULL to the sqliteDB, but with the Flt2Null = null, it raises an exception... can anybody say to me why???
Thanks for helping so far...

Comment: This doesn't look quite right, your sql query would not compile. I can't work out whether the column names are variables or part of the `String`. Please correct your query. Also, consider using [`SET` syntax](http://milov.nl/2836)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at the signature of `PreparedStatement.setFloat()`:

```
void setFloat(int parameterIndex, float x) throws SQLException
```

As you can see, it uses primitive type `float` instead of wrapper type `Float`, therefore you cannot pass `null` to it. Attempt to convert `null` value of type `Float` to `float` causes `NullPointerException`.

`String` is a reference type, therefore you can pass `null` to `PreparedStatement.setString()`.

So, in the case of `setFloat()` you have to check for `null` and use `setNull()` to pass it:

```
public static void setFloatOrNull(PreparedStatement ps, int index, Float value) {
    if (value == null) {
        ps.setNull(index, Types.FLOAT);
    } else {
        ps.setFloat(index, value);
    }
}
```